# experience with eOS and Lenovo Thinkpad x1 carbon

Tags: hardware, laptop

as mentioned in a previous post I am testing elementary os in a VM for a couple of days now to test if I can leave Windows... hopefully forever :)

there are some small points which I already mentioned when it comes to eOS itself but other than that the distro is running perfect and I found applications for every purpase.

There are some things I cannot test with my VM. Especially when it comes to hardware compaptility. I want to go for a Lenovo Thinkpad x1 carbon 7th generation and I want to know if anyone here has experience with this laptop

things which are important to me:

- touchpad support with gestures (I already went throw a thread where I can install some libraries and also a GUI for configuring gestures, not sure where I have the link)
- fn keys support for music control etc.

and generall hardware support for Lenovo and the specific laptop.
the other model will be a new XPS13 in case of any issues with the x1

every input is very welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a nice machine, and you'll be glad to know that it is [certified to run Ubuntu 18.04](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201904-26993). Since elementary OS Juno is based on Ubuntu, I foresee no issues in installing it. You might need a kernel update though, but there are also reports that it works just fine with elementary OS current kernel (4.15). [This report](https://thornelabs.net/posts/installing-ubuntu-1804-lts-on-a-lenovo-thinkpad-x1-carbon-gen-6.html) also lists the recommended BIOS setup needed to enable various features, and a list of possible issues you might encounter. [This Lenovo forum thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Lenovo-X1-Carbon-7th-Gen-Issues-with-trackpad-and-sleep/td-p/4496012) has comprehensive details on how to solve those issues.

A good start would be to [create an elementary OS USB drive](https://www.lifewire.com/create-elementary-os-live-usb-drive-2202054), and trying it live, without installing. Until elementary OS 5.1 is released, after the installation completes, you could try running `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04` [to bump up the kernel to 5.0 and to bring improved hardware support](https://blog.elementary.io/updates-for-august-2019/).

For the touchpad gestures, I can recommend [installing fusuma](https://dev.to/iberianpig/how-to-install-and-customize-fusuma-73l). It works great, but it does not have a GUI configuration tool.

As a rule of thumb, almost any Ubuntu 18.04 functionality tutorial/wiki (except the UI/UX) will also work for elementary OS.

Comment: perfectly answered! thank you for you input

Comment: @dford [This ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_(Gen_7)) also contains lots of valuable information. Enjoy your awesome elementary OS powered laptop!